# Add Item to ListBox from TextBox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have this `ListBox`:

```
<ListBox x:Name="PlaylistList" AlternationCount="2" SelectionChanged="DidChangeSelection">
        <ListBox.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle />
        </ListBox.GroupStyle>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

And i want to add option to add new item to the `ListBox`. And i want to do it by adding a `TextBox` to the `ListBox` when the user press a Button and then the user press enter and add the text in the `TextBox` to the `ListBox`.

I try to add text box to the listbox but i can add only one type of `ListBox.ItemTemplate`, how can i handle it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated** to add textbox inside Listbox:

To add new item into ListBox, in Button Click code-behind do:

```
TextBox TextBoxItem = new TextBox();
// set TextBoxItem properties here
PlaylistList.Items.Add(TextBoxItem);
```

Comment: But how i add a new item that will be a textbox

Answer (score 0):

Your ListBox:

```
<ListBox
    Name="MyListBox"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Reason}"
    DisplayMemberPath="Description"/>
```

Make a ObversableCollection for the Items of the ListBox

```
public ObservableCollection<IdObject> items
{
    get { return (ObservableCollection<IdObject>)GetValue(ApplicationsProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ApplicationsProperty, value); }
}

items = new ObservableCollection<IdObject>();
```

My ID-Object in this case has the following properties:

```
private int _id = 0;
private string _description = "";
```

Bind the collection to the ListBox:

```
MyListBox.ItemsSource = items;
```

Then make a TextBox with a Button, and an event for pressing the button, where you add the text to the observable collection:

```
items.Add(new IdObject(someId, TextBox.Text));
```

The ListBox will update, when the ObservableCollection is changed

Comment: But how i add the Text box to be one of the Items?

Comment: So you want the TextBox to be inside the ListBox?

Comment: Sorry, i don't know iTunes, post a link where such a box is shown

Answer (score 0):

Write this code when your button is clicked so that the textbox text will be added to the listbox.

```
private void addEventButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        // Adds events to listbox. 
       if (this.titleTextBox.Text != "")
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(this.titleTextBox.Text); 
            listBox2.Items.Add(this.titleTextBox.Text);
            this.titleTextBox.Focus();
            this.titleTextBox.Clear();

         }
      }
```